# I need some help adding a gradient to a texture

Tags: html, css, gradient

I would like to try and add a centered gradient to the texture in the link below.

http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#carbon-fibre

I would like each side to be #2a2b2c and the center to start at #555454.

My CSS is a bit weak, can someone help me out and maybe point out where I could learn how these methods work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.myDiv {
 margin: 0;
 height: 500px;
 width: 500px;
 background:
 radial-gradient(black 15%, transparent 16%) 0 0,
 radial-gradient(black 15%, transparent 16%) 8px 8px,
 radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.1) 15%, transparent 20%) 0 1px,
 radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.1) 15%, transparent 20%) 8px 9px;
 background-color:#282828;
 background-size:16px 16px;
 position: relative;
}

.myDiv:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#2a2b2c , #555454); /* Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
 background: -o-radial-gradient(#2a2b2c , #555454); /* For Opera 11.6 to 12.0 */
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(#2a2b2c , #555454); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
 background: radial-gradient(#2a2b2c , #555454); /* Standard syntax */
 height: 500px;
 width: 500px;
 opacity: 0.7
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: You are Welcome! @Brad_ZA

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background: rgba(42,43,44,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(42,43,44,1) 0%, rgba(85,84,84,1) 50%, rgba(42,43,44,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(42,43,44,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(85,84,84,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(42,43,44,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(42,43,44,1) 0%, rgba(85,84,84,1) 50%, rgba(42,43,44,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(42,43,44,1) 0%, rgba(85,84,84,1) 50%, rgba(42,43,44,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(42,43,44,1) 0%, rgba(85,84,84,1) 50%, rgba(42,43,44,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(42,43,44,1) 0%, rgba(85,84,84,1) 50%, rgba(42,43,44,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2a2b2c', endColorstr='#2a2b2c', GradientType=1 );
```

Use this site http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator

and this for animate gradinet:  https://www.gradient-animator.com/

Comment: I wanted to add the gradient to this, http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#carbon-fibre